# Disable operations for entire table's row

Tags: javascript

I have a table with user interaction controls in its cells (button, link, etc.) and I want to "grayed" some rows of that table so all operations of these rows will be disabled.

Any idea what's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

a button can be set to `disabled`, but a link still should work. A possible technique could set the href as a temporary property like `data-link=" ... the link ... "` and then use javascript to place it as a property href when becoming enabled.

Creating a disabled css class may also help give the ilusion of a disabled link.

jQuery would become handy here but inst required.

Comment: what I had in my mind is to create a new div that will wrap the relevant tr element that will create a new layer over the entire row and will grayed it and disable all its element.